# Undefined variable $alert-padding-y

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

I have imported my css and js files and started my web app but this is what is shown as soon as I access the page. I have imported bootstrap and added a line to precompile but the error still shows up. Is there something I am missing out?

Error:

```
SassC::SyntaxError - Error: Undefined variable: "$alert-padding-y".
        on line 7:12 of app/assets/stylesheets/scss/bootstrap/_alert.scss
>>   padding: $alert-padding-y $alert-padding-x;
   -----------^:
  app/assets/stylesheets/scss/bootstrap/_alert.scss:7:in `'
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:27
```

`application.scss`:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, or any plugin's
 * vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS/SCSS
 * files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
// Custom bootstrap variables must be set or imported *before* bootstrap.
@import "bootstrap";
```

`application.rb`:

```
require_relative "boot"

require "rails/all"

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Ruby
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 6.1
    # config.assets.precompile << %w( *.scss *.js )
    config.assets.precompile = ['.js', '.css', '*.css.erb']
    
    # Configuration for the application, engines, and railties goes here.
    #
    # These settings can be overridden in specific environments using the files
    # in config/environments, which are processed later.
    #
    # config.time_zone = "Central Time (US & Canada)"
    # config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join("extras")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to the fact that you have placed bootstrap inside of your `app/assets/stylesheets` directory which is being gulped by Sprockets.

```
// *= require_tree .
```

Will require any of the files in the `app/assets/stylesheets` directory and any of its subfolders.

[Sprockets directives](https://github.com/rails/sprockets#directives) are very primitive and [do not work well with SASS](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails#important-note). It will take each required file and send it through the SASS compliler individually which leads errors with undefined variables, functions and mixins.

To fix the problem you should:

- Move library code out of `app/assets`. Place it in `vendor/assets`, use a [gemified version of the asset](https://rubygems.org/gems/bootstrap) or a frontend package manager like Yarn to install it.
- Get rid of any sprockets directives from `application.scss`. Use the sass native `@import` directive instead.

I usually additionally [turn off the assets generator](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/reduce-application-clutter-disable-unwanted-rails) in Rails which generates a JS and CSS file every time you run the scaffold or controller generators - its a pretty flawed method of code organization anyways.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I've removed it and it seems that my stylesheets are not taking effect on the site. Would it be better if I had uninstalled sprockets?